# Shift/Ctrl: Bind to mousebuttons 4+5 as secondary key

Tags: shortcut, customization, mouse

I'm using a 5-button mouse and like to assign Shift to MB4 and Ctrl to MB5. I *could* do this with the mouse software (Razer Synapse) itself, but often it does not switch back the profiles and I have the Blender keybinding in other applications.

So, is there a way to bind the MB as secondary keys for Shift/Ctrl inside Blender?